# What's the difference using the command cat < file.txt and cat file.txt?

Tags: shell, command

I don't have clear how tu use < to redirect the stdin. What is the difference between using the command cat file.txt and cat < file.txt? With this example the output would be the content of file.txt. Can anyone use a better example to show how to use

Im studying command lines, and I saw this example for using <:

cat < file.txt

But I don't see good with this example the purpose of <.

cat < file.txt

I would like somebody to explain  how to use < and an example because I still haven't finded a good explanation of the use of <.

I found an example that I find very useful and clear about the use of < in a forum, but would like to know if its 100% correct:

You want to know why do we use ‘<’ if we can cat file.txt (rather than
cat < file.txt).

When you ‘cat file.txt’ with content 1, 2, 3, it prints 1, 2, 3.
If you have a file abc with a function “def abc(x, y, z)” and you want to test the function with inputs 1, 2, 3 (pass 1, 2, 3 values to variables x, y, z ) that are stored in file.txt. you can use “cat abc < file.txt” instead of type 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Some programs are purely filters, such as `tr` which transliterates one or more characters into one or more other characters, and do not read from or write to files, they just read `stdin` and write `stdout`. So if you try to transliterate `a` into `b` Like this `tr a b` you will be waiting a long time. Next time you will run `tr a b < someFile`

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO!

In reality, those two examples, `cat file.txt` and `cat < file.txt` are exactly the same.

The use of ">" shows up when you want to add text to another file. For example, `cat > file2.txt < file.txt`. In there, the content of file.txt goes to file2.txt. If you didn't add the `< file.txt` you would have to write down the content.

Hope I helped, if you have more questions, don't doubt to ask them!

Comment: They are not *exactly* the same; in one `cat` has to open a file, while in the other it just reads from its standard input. I'm not sure why you are brining `>` into the answer.

Comment: @chepner I meant that the result is exactly the same in those examples. I bring `>` into the answer so he can see where the use of `<` would be helpful, although not necessary.

Comment: `cat file.txt > file2.txt` would do the same; it doesn't demonstrate why `<` would be useful.

Comment: @chepner I already said it's not necessary, but I considerated it helpful to make him understand the concept. If you think you can make a better answer for him to get the point, please, be my guest.